# Implementation of the quick select algorithm to find kth smallest number

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I'm currently working on a program to find the kth smallest number of an array using the quick select algorithm. I've finished it and it works but does not give the correct result every time.

Here's my code (I didn't include my `partition` or `swap` algorithm, I'm fairly sure they're correct):

```
/*
inputs...
*A: pointer to array
n: size of array
k: the item in question
*/
int ksmallest(int *A, int n, int k){

    int left = 0; 
    int right = n - 1; 
    int next = 1;

    return quickselect(A, left, right, k);
}

int quickselect(int *A, int left, int right, int k){

    //p is position of pivot in the partitioned array
    int p = partition(A, left, right);

    //k equals pivot got lucky
    if (p - 1 == k - 1){
        return A[p];
    }
    //k less than pivot
    else if (k - 1 < p - 1){
        return quickselect(A, left, p - 1, k);
    }
    //k greater than pivot
    else{
        return quickselect(A, p + 1, right, k);
    }
}
```

Everything compiles fine. I then tried to use the program on the following array: `[1,3,8,2,4,9,7]`

These were my results:

```
> kthsm 2
4
> kthsm 1
1
> kthsm 3
2
```

As you can see, it worked correctly on the 1th smallest item, but failed on the others. What could be the problem? I guessed than my indexing was off but I'm not exactly sure.

EDIT: Added my partition and swap code below, as requested:

```
int partition(int *A, int left, int right){

    int pivot = A[right], i = left, x;

    for (x = left; x < right - 1; x++){
        if (A[x] <= pivot){
            swap(&A[i], &A[x]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    swap(&A[i], &A[right]);
    return i;
}

//Swaps
void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger. For such a small array it should not be to hard even with the recursion.

Comment: So let's see - you've got a bug, you don't know where it is, and you didn't include all the code. Hmmm...you should really include the `partition` and `swap` code.

Comment: Also, you can try to implement a quicksort first, then think about when to stop the quicksort algorithm to obtain your quickselect solution. Because this is basically what happens. Quicksort as long as it takes to reach partition sizes of size k.

Comment: Are you sure you want `x < right - 1` and not `x < right` or even `x <= right`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I changed that line, but now the program consistently returns the kth+1 smallest item

Comment: I just changed the above comment. `right` was set from the array length as `right = n - 1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the equals sign crashes the program, as does `x <= right + 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your partition function the loop condition should be `x < right`, not `x < right - 1`.

Also, in the if statements in quickselect, you should switch both uses of `p-1` to `p`. `p` is already an index and by decreasing `k` by 1 you turn it into an index(rather than an order) as well. There is no need to decrease `p` by one again.

```
int partition(int *A, int left, int right){
    int pivot = A[right], i = left, x;
 
    for (x = left; x < right; x++){
        if (A[x] < pivot){
            swap(&A[i], &A[x]);
            i++;
        }
    }
 
    swap(&A[i], &A[right]);
    return i;
}
 
 
int quickselect(int *A, int left, int right, int k){
 
    //p is position of pivot in the partitioned array
    int p = partition(A, left, right);
 
    //k equals pivot got lucky
    if (p == k-1){
        return A[p];
    }
    //k less than pivot
    else if (k - 1 < p){
        return quickselect(A, left, p - 1, k);
    }
    //k greater than pivot
    else{
        return quickselect(A, p + 1, right, k);
    }
}
```

Here's a working example. http://ideone.com/Bkaglb

Comment: This crashes the program

Comment: @PythonNewb added a link to ideone so you may experiment with it. It did seem to work on with k values 1 to 5 when I ran it.

Comment: Indeed this works, however it's off by one, the 0th smallest item returns 1, when the 1st smallest item should return 1, correct?

Comment: @PythonNewb I assumed k was a positive integer. (i.e. I figured there can't be a 0th smallest number, but the smallest number would actually be 1st smallest number) If that assumption holds, this works fine. If you are planning to assign the value of k in range [0, n-1], then you should simply replace both **k-1** in if statements with k and you'd get what you want. The code is basically the same. You just have to make the distinction whether k is an index or a value indicating the order of the element. (i.e. 0-indexed or 1-indexed)

Comment: I don't think this matters much, but the original 1965 implementation uses `if (A[x] < pivot)` (instead of `<=`). There's no point in swapping values equal to the pivot.

Comment: Is there an implementation with no recursion? Will it be faster?